# How to plot specific colors and shapes for ggplot2 scatter plot?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, shapes

I've been trying to make a scatter plot using ggplot2 where the points are both a custom set of colors and shapes but haven't gotten exactly what I wanted.

The following code gives me the correct shapes, but only two colors (purple and blue):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat$PC2, y=dat$PC3)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=dat$color, shape=dat$shape)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=dat$color) +
  ggtitle("PC Scores") +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

The following code still gives me the correct shapes, but does now show color differentiation. But, while the points that need to be different colors are now different colors, they are not the right colors. Instead of the colors I want, it looks like it goes with a default palette.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat$PC2, y=dat$PC3)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(dat$color), shape=dat$shape)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=dat$color) +
  ggtitle("PC Scores") +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Where am I going wrong with the colors? I've tried switching from color to fill commands, but I just can't seem to get the right combination. Is it because I repeat colors?

Here is a sample of the data (`dat`) I'm trying to plot:

```
PC2 PC3 color   shape
-0.14   -0.22   purple  21
-0.04   -0.18   purple  21
0.12    -0.04   purple  21
0.34    0.08    blue    21
-0.06   -0.29   blue    21
0.13    -0.09   blue    21
0.02    0.02    blue    21
0.07    -0.12   orange  21
0.09    -0.10   orange  21
0.17    -0.06   orange  21
0.57    0.59    red 22
0.13    -0.01   red 22
0.26    0.19    red 22
0.18    0.07    red 21
0.13    -0.03   red 21
-0.19   -0.06   purple  22
-0.08   -0.04   purple  22
-0.03   -0.07   purple  22
0.12    -0.03   black   24
0.03    -0.19   black   24
0.11    -0.06   black   24
-0.42   0.29    blue    22
-0.63   0.39    blue    22
-0.57   0.32    blue    22
-0.23   0.16    blue    22
0.14    -0.05   purple  24
0.31    -0.15   purple  24
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: you should not repeat `dat$` inside `aes`, so `ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat$PC2, y=dat$PC3)) +` should be `ggplot(dat, aes(x=PC2, y=PC3)) +`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you have to set the factor levels before plotting and you need to set the colornames as a character vector:

```
# set the levels of dat$color in the right order
dat$color <- factor(dat$color, levels = c("purple","blue","orange","red","black"))
# create a character vector of colornames
colr <- as.character(unique(dat$color))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=PC2, y=PC3)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=color, shape=factor(shape))) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=unique(dat$color), values=colr)
```

this gives:

[image]

*Note: I didn't remove the legend for illustrative reasons.*

Comment: The colors are not correct here. For example the point (0.57, 0.59) should be red.

Comment: Thank you @Jaap - this is exactly what I wanted, and I understand my error(s) now.

Comment: @GeorgeDontas thanx for pointing me to the error, the code and plot are now correct

Answer (score 4):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=PC2, y=PC3)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=color, shape=factor(shape))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values= levels(dat$color)) +
  ggtitle("PC Scores")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @george-dontas !